# Hazard ratios for three groups - does deleting one group affect the remaining ratio?

Tags: cox-model, hazard

My study originally had 3 groups, x , y and z.

Hazard ratios were reported for x vs y, x vs z and y vs z.

If we remove group z from the study, would the x vs y hazard ratio change?

If someone can clarify, I would be appreciative.

Comment: How were the hazard ratios calculated?

Comment: Cox proportional models.